# Getting enum object from string when enum values are tuples?

Tags: python, enums

I have `Enum` of the form

```
class ItemType(Enum):
    ITEM1 = ('Desc1', AnotherEnum.ONE)
    ITEM2 = ('Desc2', AnotherEnum.TWO)
```

and I am trying to instantiate an object of the type `ItemType` from a JSON string.

For example I would like to get the `ItemType` that logically represents the string `'Desc1'`. If the enum values were of the form `ITEM1 = 'Desc1'` I could simple do `ItemType('Desc1')`. But in the current form I am not sure how I could achieve the lookup method.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: In place of the `class` or the values of the `Enum`?

Comment: Use another enum called `Desc`, then you can do `ItemType(Desc('Desc1'))`

Comment: @smac89 Can you turn that into an answer? I'd like to see the full example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An `Enum` is just a `class`, so how about an alternate constructor? It's the most explicit.

```
class ItemType(Enum):
    ITEM1 = ('Desc1', AnotherEnum.ONE)
    ITEM2 = ('Desc2', AnotherEnum.TWO)
    
    @classmethod
    def from_description(cls, description):
        for item in cls:
            if item.value[0] == description:
                return item
        raise ValueError("%r is not a valid %s description" % (description, cls.__name__))
```

You can then do `ItemType.from_description('Desc1')`.

Alternatively, if you want `ItemType('Desc1')` to just work, as of Python 3.6 you can implement `_missing_`:

```
class ItemType(Enum):
    ITEM1 = ('Desc1', AnotherEnum.ONE)
    ITEM2 = ('Desc2', AnotherEnum.TWO)
    
    @classmethod
    def _missing_(cls, value):
        for item in cls:
            if item.value[0] == value:
                return item
        return super()._missing_(value)
```

I'd base my choice on whether looking up by description is a natural thing to do or not. If it's specific to translating JSON, rather stick with the alternate constructor. Otherwise, sure, go for this second option. However, in that case I'd wonder if the value is the best place to store the related `AnotherEnum`. Maybe instead you should have a method `to_another_enum()`, an alternate constructor on `AnotherEnum`, or both...?